# Selenium C# Any alternative way of finding if element is present on browser other than IsElementPresent(By by)

Tags: c#, html, selenium, automated-tests

I have a scenario where there are three distinct html parent elements

```
<tr class="s3288" data-id="s3288">
<tr class="s3288" data-id="s3288">
<tr class="s1" data-id="s1">
```

Two these elements have a child element

```
<a class="gylink mapvl" title="No Map Values" href="#">Map Values</a>
```

but third one does not have this child element. 
in my test scenario, I have to click this child element if present.
Is there any function by which i can detect if this element is present?
I have used following function bug for some reason it does not work properly

function i used

```
protected bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            wait.Until(drv => (drv.FindElement(by)));
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is how the html of browser looks like

```
<tr class="s1" data-id="s1">
<td class="ftc1">
<td class="ftc2">
<td class="ftc3 valuecol">
<td class="ftc4 headcol">
<ul class="multihead">
<li>
<input class="txtinput chghead headcolfield pholder changit requiref" type="text" placeholder="Enter Column Header Value" validate="{required: true, messages: {required: 'Required'}}" name="th_s1_0_true" value="">
<a class="gylink mapvl" title="No Map Values" href="#">Map Values</a>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="ftc5 deletecol"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="s3288" data-id="s3288">
<td class="ftc1">
<td class="ftc2">
<td class="ftc3 valuecol">
<td class="ftc4 headcol">
<ul class="multihead">
<li>
<input class="txtinput chghead headcolfield pholder changit requiref" type="text" placeholder="Enter Column Header Value" validate="{required: true, messages: {required: 'Required'}}" name="th_s3288_0_true" value="">
<a class="gylink mapvl" title="No Map Values" href="#">Map Values</a>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="ftc5 deletecol"> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="t1" data-id="t1">
<td class="ftc1">
<td class="ftc2">
<td class="ftc3 valuecol">
<td class="ftc4 headcol">
<ul class="multihead">
<li>
<input class="txtinput chghead headcolfield pholder changit requiref" type="text" placeholder="Enter Column Header Value" validate="{required: true, messages: {required: 'Required'}}" name="th_t1_0_true" value="">
</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td class="ftc5 deletecol"> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The problem is that defining something as "visible" or "displayed" simply isn't a black or white thing. There are many different scenarios that must be catered for. Regardless "not work", means *what*?

Comment: In this scenario my function should return true two times and false third time. But seems like it is returning true all 3 times